# how to update div in other ctp file from another ctp file using Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am using Ajax link to update div in my view page. Example : I have 2 ctp file say view1.ctp and

view2.ctp, I want to update the div in the view1.ctp using the ajax call in view2.ctp. Can anybody

give me the hint to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance
Pushpa

Comment: We need to see some code before we can help with this...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) for a better approach.

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('view2.ctp', function(data) {
        $('#divview1').html(data);
    });
</script>
```

and in view1.ctp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadData(){
                $.get('view2.ctp', function(data) {
                    $('#divview1').html(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divview1"></div> <a href="#" onclick="loadData()">Load data from view2.ctp</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you don't want to use jQuery you can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), but jQuery is way more easier to use.